# Why does mysqli_stmt::free_result have different behavior when using the MySQLnd driver vs the libmysql driver?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a greatly simplified example to illustrate the behavior I'm seeing.  If you create the following table and run the following php script, you'll get the behavior I'm describing:

```
<?php
/*
CREATE TABLE Testing (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Testing VALUES (1,'One'),(2,'Two'),(3,'Three'),(4,'Four'),(5,'Five');
*/

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);
$stmtQuery = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM Testing WHERE id = ?");
$stmtQuery->bind_result($id, $name);

for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $stmtQuery->bind_param('i', $i);
    $stmtQuery->execute();
    $stmtQuery->store_result();
    $stmtQuery->fetch();
    $stmtQuery->free_result();
    
    error_log("$id, $name");
}

$stmtQuery->close();
?>
```

On a machine with libmysql as the driver (5.3.10 in my case), this results in the following output:

```
1, One
2, Two
3, Three
4, Four
5, Five
```

On a machine with MySQLnd as the driver (both 5.3.10 and 5.4.24), this results in the following:

```
1, One
1, One
1, One
1, One
1, One
```

I'm stumped as to why.  I can see ways around it, but I'd like to actually understand what's going on.

- If I remove the `free_result()` call, I get the expected behavior in all circumstances.
- If I move the `bind_result` statement inside the loop, it also fixes the problem, but I thought the bind_result is supposed to be outside the loop when doing something like this.

The reason why this matters is because we're going to be migrating to 5.5 and the default driver under 5.5 is MySQLnd.  If we've been doing something wrong with how and when we use store_result that's being exposed by how the MySQLnd driver works, I'd like to catch and fix that now, as opposed to later.

So, any thoughts?

Comment: try moving your `->bind()` call outside of the loop. binding should normally only be done once, and sets up a direct link between the specified placeholder and the specified variable, e.g a reference. if `nd` is optimizing things by binding directly to the value and then realizing you're just binding the same var over and over again, it might decide to skip that step since it appears to be redundant.

Comment: Though I admit this comment is OT, I just have to say thank you for posting a good question, interesting, researched, targeting recent PHP versions, this is sooooo much better than 99% of all the PHP questions we see here.

Comment: Marc B, which bind call are you referring to?  In my example, the bind_result() is already outside of the loop, and bind_param() must be inside the loop.  If it wasn't, there would be no way to call the mysql select statement repeatedly with different values of `id` in the where clause.  And Michael, thanks!

Comment: Well, I learned that I already posed my question wrong:  store_result() isn't the issue, free_result() is. I can just comment out free_result() and it works fine in all cases. I tried putting in a debug_zval_dump($id) before and after the free_result() call.  When using the libmysqlclient driver the refcount is 1 both before and after the free_result() call (Note that debug_zval_dump creates a reference to the variable so that's actually a refcount of 0). When using the MySQLnd client, the refcount is 1 before the free_result() call but 2 after. Still investigating what to make of that...

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified that the problem is with [`mysqli_stmt::free_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php). This is yet another reason why it's a really bad idea to manually close and free mysqli internal resources in PHP. You don't need to do it, let PHP handle it automatically.

`mysqli_stmt::free_result()` isn't documented very well in PHP manual. This function does the following:

> Frees the internal result memory associated with the statement, including buffered & unbuffered data, and all variable references bound to it.

This means that when you call this function it will unbind the variables bound with `bind_result()`. **You must bind the variables inside the loop or remove `$stmtQuery->free_result()`**. Because the variables are only bound to the first result, their value will always show you the value from the first result.

### Why is there a difference between mysqlnd and libmysqlclient

I can't confirm that there is a difference because I haven't got access to a machine with libmysqlclient, but the difference likely comes from the following two reasons:

1. MySQL native driver for PHP implemented this function differently due to internal reasons.
2. There is/was a bug with mysqlnd or libmysqlclient.